# Search for more than one keyword - SQL Statement - Access database

Tags: asp.net, sql, ms-access, visual-studio-2008

I am testing an asp.net website with Visual Studio 2008. The website uses an ACCESS database. The following search query works fine if the user inputs one keyword only in the search field. For more than 1 keyword the select statement returns null result. Is there any way to restrusture the SQL statement so that more than 1 keyword can be searchable?

```
SelectCommand="SELECT [title] FROM [recipe] WHERE ([title] LIKE '%' + ? + '%')">
<SelectParameters>
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="searchField" Name="title" 
PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
</SelectParameters>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the separator you are using between different keywords (eg. a comma or a space)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since MS ACCESS doesn't support full text search I think I solved the problem so that it is possible to search a table(s) using multiple keywords from a single text-box form field. Here is the script. It works well so far. Is there any way to make this script even better????

Thanks

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.OleDb" %>

<script runat="server">    
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If IsPostBack Then

        Dim dbconn, sql, dbcomm, dbread, searchTxt, arrText, intCount
        searchTxt = Request.Form("TextBox1")
        arrText = Split(searchTxt)
        'Response.Write(search)

        dbconn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source=" & Server.MapPath("App_Data/MyRecipes.mdb"))
        dbconn.Open()
        For intCount = 0 To UBound(arrText)
            sql = "SELECT * FROM recipe WHERE title LIKE '%" + arrText(intCount) + "%' "
        Next
        dbcomm = New OleDbCommand(sql, dbconn)
        dbread = dbcomm.ExecuteReader()
        customers.DataSource = dbread
        customers.DataBind()
        dbread.Close()
        dbconn.Close()
    End If

End Sub
</script>

<body>
<form id="Form1" runat="server">
<asp:Repeater id="customers" runat="server">

<HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>

<ItemTemplate>
<div style="display:block;">
<%#Container.DataItem("title")%>
</div>
</ItemTemplate>

<FooterTemplate></FooterTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
</form>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Gloria, You could change after `where` like below example

```
  [title] Like 1st criteria OR [title] Like 2nd criteria OR  [title] Like 3rd criteria;
```

Comment: Thanks but the above doesn't work in my case because there is only ONE text input search field, not many. Besides there is no limit to how many words a user can enter in the search field. I was thinking to use a loop that takes each word in the text field and make a search on that word and then goes to the second one. Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: Okay...Thats sounds right ....i would have restrict user in this scenario for entering values either by space or by a comma and then you could split them using `String.split(',')` or `whitespce` and loop through to generate a chain of likes...